# missing values in a data table in R

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a data table `A` which has a column `right_date`. When I look at the column `right_date`, it seems there are 486 missing values in it. But when I drop the rows with missing values in the column `right_date` of `A`, with `na.omit(A, cols="right_date")` from the [R documentation page](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/na.omit.data.table.html),then 1,156 rows are dropped.

I do not know why this is happening. 
it seems `DataCombine::DropNA(DT, Var="")` is consistent with missing values just in `right_date_vect` , it drops 486 rows.

here is the data if you want to try https://drive.google.com/file/d/1diq9ctwen6jqfRFlV24qG8PKqdFcBqhu/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide code snippets and sample data in your question rather than pictures or links to other websites.

Comment: Does `is.data.table(A)` return TRUE? My guess is it is not, and `na.omit()` is a generic, so the cols is silently discarded if it is only a data.frame or matrix instead.

Comment: @smingerson you are right! There should be an error or warning or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object "A" in the question was not, in fact, a data.table. `na.omit()` is a generic method, and extra arguments can get eaten by the dots. So, while no error was thrown, either `na.omit.matrix()` or `na.omit.data.frame()` was called instead, which would omit any row with an NA value.

This is a curse of the S3 system which can bite you. When I receive unexpected output, the first thing is I do is, for example, execute `na.omit` (no parentheses) at the console. This will print the function definition. If I see something like `UseMethod("na.omit")`, that indicates behavior differs by class, so then I check the class of my object.

The R package [ellipsis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ellipsis/readme/README.html) is aimed at addressing this deficiency. Below is a way to stop this from happening again (based very much so on that readme!)

```r
library(data.table)
library(ellipsis)
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, NA), nrow = 2)
colnames(mat) <- c("a", "b")
safe_na.omit <- function(object, ...) {
  check_dots_used()
  na.omit(object, ...)
}

safe_na.omit(mat, col = "a")
#> Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.
#> 
#> We detected these problematic arguments:
#> * `col`
#> 
#> Did you misspecify an argument?

dt <- as.data.table(mat)
safe_na.omit(dt, cols = "a")
#>    a  b
#> 1: 1  3
#> 2: 2 NA
```